# Accessing downstream annotations of a node in Rascal

Tags: rascal

Simple question: in Rascal how does one access annotations of descendants of a node?  GetTraversalContextNodes() returns upstream nodes -- "myContext[-1]" doesn't work.  getChildren() returns a list of children, but the list is a list of values.  The Name@Annotation syntax requires that "Name" be a node. What magic do you do on "Name" to get it to refer to a node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the children that are themselves nodes, you could use code like the following:

```
list[node] nl = [ n | node n <- getChildren(currentNode)];
```

This would get back all the children, filtering out any that are not of type `node`.